# FluxCD notification error sending to Microsoft Teams

Tags: kubernetes, fluxcd

I am trying to configure FluxCD in Kubernetes to send notifications to Microsfot Teams for reconciliation events.

I have followed the FluxCD "[Setup Notifications](https://fluxcd.io/docs/guides/notifications/)" instructions. Everything is deployed as expected.

[image]

I am not receiving any alerts in Teams as expected when I edit a config (e.g. pod replicaCount) and run "flux reconcile ...". This is the error I am seeing in the Notification Controller

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the secret with the Microsoft Teams channel URL

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas to please share with me today. Thank you

Comment: Can you share the yaml (secrets redacted) to give a bit more clarity on the setup?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the secret containing the Microsoft Teams URL. The URL is base64'd and in the format 

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/<some stuff>/General?groupId=<id>&tenantId=<id>

Thank you

Comment: could you include the provider and alert yaml too please, that was more what I meant?

Comment: Oh of course, sorry about that. Thank you. Added

Comment: these look right, could be a bug, have you reached out to the Flux maintainers or community in slack?

Comment: So I asked a question to the Flux team and first thing that came up was I had not setup an incoming webhook on Teams using these instructions https://fluxcd.io/docs/components/notification/provider/#ms-teams. However, when I did this I then ended up with the following error:

failed to initialize provider, error: invalid MS Teams webhook URL https://mycompany.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/edc0165a-6d60-4674-a173-3985bd2cdfa3@ce846fab-cc1c-465b-5432-18f07c9ac198/IncomingWebhook/cea31703336a4c201213226b4615dbcd/cfe4915g-54d9-456b-a238-8dc4727c8er0. 

I am now waiting for suggestions from them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, firstly, I had not created an incoming webhook in Microsoft Teams UI: https://fluxcd.io/docs/components/notification/provider/#ms-teams

Secondly, I asked a question to the Flux maintainers as @Nalum suggested and there was a follow-on issue with encoding the Teams URL correctly. I had a trailing newline character which caused the URL to be invalid as reported by the Provider. I was reciving the following error

[image]

To resolve this I had to use the -n switch on the echo command when base64'ing the Teams URL for the Secret in Kubernetes.

```
echo -n '<teams url>' | base64
```

My final Kubernetes config was as follows:
[image]

[image]

[image]

A full breakdown of the investigation can be seen here: https://github.com/fluxcd/flux2/discussions/2719